# Spring data and junit

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i have a problem where i want to test spring data with junit. I use spring data jpa with junit 4 :

this is my test class

```
 @ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
    @Transactional
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    public class EquipementServiceTest1 {

       @Autowired
        IEquipementService equipmentservice;
        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            equipmentservice=new EquipementService();
        }

        @Test
        public void testValidateEquipement() {
           equipementEntity e =new equipementEntity();
           e.setCode("10");
           e.setLibelle("yyyy");
           equipmentservice.validateEquipement(e);
        }

        @Test
        public void testGetListEquipement() {
            List<equipementEntity> list=new ArrayList<equipementEntity>();
            list=   equipmentservice.getListEquipement();
                assertEquals(list.size(), 2);`enter code here`
        }

        @Service
    public class EquipementService implements IEquipementService {

        @Autowired
        EquipementRepository equipementRepository;`enter code here

        @Override
        public List<equipementEntity> getListEquipement() {
            return equipementRepository.findAll();
        }
```

i have a null pointer exception
thank you very much

Comment: Where exactly do you get an exception?

Comment: this my log java.lang.NullPointerException
 at app.services.equipementEntite.EquipementService.getListEquipement(EquipementService.java:29)
 at app.services.equipementEntite.EquipementServiceTest1.testGetListEquipement(EquipementServiceTest1.java:45)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of stuff going on here. You autowire `EquipmentService` but you don't specify the configuration, so the service is not being autowired. Even if it was, you reset it in the `setUp` method. The new `equipmentservice` does not have repository set, so `NullPointerException` is probably thrown at the point `equipmentservice` tries to call repository.

This is pretty easy to resolve using `@ContextConfiguration` and `Mockito` mock objects ( I am assuming repository is autowired)

1. For you test class add  `@ContextConfiguration` annontation.
2. Add inner static configuration class to your test
3. In the configuration make repository a mock object

   ```
   @Transactional
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @ContextConfiguration
   public class EquipementServiceTest1 {
          @Autowired
           IEquipementService equipmentservice;
           @Before
           public void setUp() throws Exception {
              //remove this 
              // equipmentservice=new EquipementService();
           }

           @Test
           public void testValidateEquipement() {
              equipementEntity e =new equipementEntity();
              e.setCode("10");
              e.setLibelle("yyyy");
              equipmentservice.validateEquipement(e);
           }

           @Test
           public void testGetListEquipement() {
               List<equipementEntity> list=new ArrayList<equipementEntity>();
               list=   equipmentservice.getListEquipement();
                   assertEquals(list.size(), 2);`enter code here`
           }

           @Service
       public class EquipementService implements IEquipementService {

           @Autowired
           EquipementRepository equipementRepository;`enter code here

           @Override
           public List<equipementEntity> getListEquipement() {
               return equipementRepository.findAll();
           }
      }
   @Configuration
   public static class Config {
   @Bean
   public IEquipementService equipmentservice {
      return new equipmentService();
   }

   @Bean
   public EquipmentRepository equipmentRepository {
     return Mockito.mock(EquimentRepository.class);
   }

   }
   ```

This obviously has not been compiled. Also `equipmentRepository` is a mock, so the call to `getListEquipment` will return empty List. If you want it to return something you can specify it using `Mockito.when` method for example. Please not, that this is a Unit Test and it is testing `EquipmentService`, not `EquipmentRepository`. If you want to test the functionality of `EquipmentRepository` you would need to create another Unit test and configure it accordingly.

Comment: despit i use <br/> : EquipementRepository equipmentRepository;  <br/> @Test
    public void testGetListEquipement() {
       // List<equipementEntity> list=new ArrayList<equipementEntity>();
        List<equipementEntity>  list=   equipmentRepository.findAll();
            assertEquals(list.size(), 2);
    }  i have the same error

Comment: its work with EquipmentRepository  thank you very much