# To write Junit Test cases for spring based REST API

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, junit

For Spring based Rest API, in order to write JUnit test cases, do I need an established database connection or can i have a mock database. Can I get some suggestions.

Technology Stack used si:
Spring MVC, 
Hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are testing. If you are testing the service layer, you should not establish actual connections to the database. Instead, you can mock up repository objects, using Mockito, for example. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978956/spring-data-and-junit) is an example of how to wire up mock Repository objects.

If you want to test your data access logic, you might consider using an in-memory database like hsqldb and define it as a test data source in the test configuration.

For more sophisticated, integration testing, you might want to connect to the actual database.

Answer (score 1):

Under your `root-context.xml` you may consider setting up different bean profiles. For example:

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/mydb"/>
        <property name="username" value="admin"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="3"/>
    </bean>
    ...
</beans>
...
<beans profile="prod">
    <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.3:3306/mydb"/>
        <property name="username" value="admin"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="3"/>
    </bean>
    ...
</beans>
```

And then under your JUnit tests you may consider using the [`@Profile`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) annotation above your tests:

```
@Profile(value="dev")
```

Alternatively, you may set the `spring.profiles.active` environment property in your `application.properties` file or as a launch configuration for your application server via `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

For more information, you may read the [Spring docs on Profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html).